# Webpack load different index file by default

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using webpack with HtmlWebpackPlugin plugin.

Let's say I have a file `foo/index.js` and if I import it as `import { foo } from './foo'` it works.

But I need to configure webpack such that if I have file `foo/index.web.js` and `import { foo } from './foo'` webpack should load `index.web.js` first.

Load order should be

1. index.web.js
2. index.js (if index.web.js not found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be only a matter of adding `.web.js` as an `extension` in webpack `resolve` configuration before the `.js`

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.web.js', '.js', '.json'],
  },
};
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

In fact create-react-app does this by default (with the `.web.js`)

Comment: oh wow, didn't know that. What meaning does the `.web.js` extension has?

Comment: @kbariotis I think it is related to react-native web platform specific implementations https://dev.to/gorbypark/react-native-web-platform-specific-web-js-extension-4o8n